Run mutable function twice, once in a loop, and once on SIGUSR1
I'm trying to write a status generator for I3, and for updating the volume indicator it requires that the program can handle SIGUSR1 requests to update the bar. I already run the generation function in a loop every 1 sec and just need to handle those requests. I'm using Tokio for the project since it can handle requests like that out of the box. My code (tell me if you need more context):

pub async fn run_bar(&mut self) {
    let interval = Duration::from_millis(self.speed);

    let og_pw_num = self.pw_color_num;

    let mut func = || {
        let mut statusline: String = String::new();
        let mut pw_color_num: usize = 0;
        pw_color_num = og_pw_num;
        let fn_list_size = self.function_list.len().clone();
        for (i, mut x) in self.function_list.iter_mut().enumerate() {
            let og_pw_num_2 = pw_color_num;
            if (pw_color_num == self.pw_colors.len()) {
                pw_color_num = og_pw_num;
            }

            if (self.is_powerline) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    //statusline.push('');
                    statusline.push_str(&format!(
                        "<span foreground='{}'></span>",
                        self.pw_colors[pw_color_num]
                    ));
                } else if pw_color_num != 0 {
                    statusline.push_str(&format!(
                        "<span background='{}' foreground='{}'></span>",
                        self.pw_colors[pw_color_num],
                        self.pw_colors[pw_color_num - 1]
                    ));
                } else {
                    statusline.push_str(&format!(
                        "<span background='{}' foreground='{}'></span>",
                        self.pw_colors[pw_color_num],
                        self.pw_colors[og_pw_num_2 - 1]
                    ));
                }
                // statusline.push_str(&format!("<span background='{}' foreground='{}'>", self.bg, self.fg));
                statusline.push_str(&format!(
                    "<span background='{}' foreground='{}'> ",
                    self.pw_colors[pw_color_num], self.fg
                ));
            }

            // always ran because they are the base command
            statusline.push_str(x.prefix().as_str());
            statusline.push_str(x.plug_out().as_str());

            if (self.is_powerline) {
                statusline.push_str(" </span>");
                if (i == fn_list_size - 1 && self.end_pw_line) {
                    statusline.push_str(&format!(
                        "<span foreground='{}' background='{}'></span>",
                        self.pw_colors[pw_color_num], self.bg
                    ))
                }
                pw_color_num += 1;
            }

            if (i != fn_list_size - 1 && !self.is_powerline) {
                statusline.push_str(self.seperator.as_str())
            }
        }
        println!("{}", statusline);
    };
    loop {
        let mut next_time = Instant::now() + interval;
        func();
        sleep(next_time - Instant::now());
        //     next_time += interval;
    }
    // let mut sigint = signal(SignalKind::user_defined1()).unwrap();

    // let sigusr1 = async { loop{ match sigint.recv().await {
    //     Some(()) => func(),
    //     None => eprintln!("Stream terminated before receiving SIGINT signal"),
    // }}};

    // let main = async {loop {
    //     func();
    //
    // }};
    //tokio::join!(main, sigusr1);
}

I tried to tokio::join! the sigusr1 waiting event and the loop but pretty obviously it wouldn't let me run since it tries to both take a mutable variable and use it.

First of, your function has a very strange and likely incorrect mix of sync and async, inside an async function a std::thread::sleep will block the worker thread and possibly the entire runtime, this should be using tokio's.

Second, join! does not make any sense, it is an AND between two one-shot future, it doesn't compose streams or anything. tokio_signal presents signal notifications as an async stream, so what you should do is inside your loop select! between the stream's next and a timer, that way if either condition is true select! returns and you can do your thing, then you loop back to waiting on your signals.

Incidentally I'm not convinced that this being a method let alone taking &mut self makes sense, it never returns so once it's called this task is completely done, and so is the object it's being called on. It might as well consume the subject, or just be a function which take whatever attributes there are as parameters.
